# What type of bolt is used to attach a sound card to an expansion plate?

Tags: sound-card, expansion-cards, screws

I'd like to replace one of the bolts attaching my sound card to its expansion plate, as shown in the picture below. (The side of the card shown in the picture actually shows the nuts; I'm talking about the bolts that would be visible on the other side) [image]

What type of bolt/screw do I need? After looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/326203/) I'm guessing M3's [such as these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00032Q1J4/ref=gno_cart_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE) - are they suitable?

Comment: I have no idea, but why do you think they would need anything special? I'd say: anything that fits would do? So just get a bolt and nut that fit together and are not wider than the current bolt and nut. And add (re-use) a washer to not damage the circuit board when fastening them. (I don't think you should get a "screw", and I doubt tgies's answer is correct, as I feel no nut will fit a 6-32 screw.)

Answer (score -1):

M3 screws are used in PCs to secure drives in their bays, but what you're looking for is the very similar [6-32 screw](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws). You can find these at better computer stores and most hardware stores.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you see the red circles in the image in the question? (Looking at the image for 6-32, I feel those are different.)