# What are the standard system unit case screw use?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, power-supply, spare-parts

I am planning to build a system unit using second-hand parts.

But these second-hand parts don't come with screws so I am thinking of buying a set but there are so many to choose from.

What is the screw used for each part?

- Motherboard
- HDD (3.5")
- HDD (2.5")
- SSD (2.5")
- GPU
- PSU
- 120mm case fan
- 240mm liquid cpu cooler

**Related:** [Is there a standard name for the "standard" computer screw?](https://superuser.com/questions/326203/is-there-a-standard-name-for-the-standard-computer-screw)

From that question, it says, 6-32 screw and M3-0.50 screw.

My question is, where is each screw used for each part mentioned above?

Comment: Just buy a computer screw set and you will have enough screws for all occurrences.   Or cannibalize computer junk, there are usually more than enough screws left in the old cases.

Comment: I've got literally a drawer full of spares that came with bits & pieces over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the specs for most computer screws (Laptops are different)

Just Google "Computer Screw Set" and you will find kits that have everything you need.

Any special screws will come with the hardware you purchase.

> Main board conventional copper column (M3 x 6 + 6)
>
> Main board fixed screws (M3 x 5)
>
> Main board insulation gasket (red M3 x 8)
>
> CD-ROM set screws (M3 x 4)
>
> Hard drive screw (M3.5 x 5)
>
> Chassis hand twist screws (silver M3.5 x 5)
>
> Chassis hand twist screw (black M3.5 x 5)
>
> Chassis high-strength screw (M3.5 x 6)
>
> Conventional chassis fan retaining screw (white zinc M5 x 10)
>
> Conventional chassis fans retaining screw (black M5 x 10)